# New web app "This page can't be displayed" SP13

Tags: 2013, web-application

When I create a Web application with different host name then a server name I recieve erorr message "this page can't be displayed"

The same if I crate a web application with my server name http://SharePointServer:80 it's working but if I change the name in AAM 
again I have the same Issue.

Comment: What u mean by different host name, DNS record? How many server in farm?

Comment: Just 1 server in a farm by host name I mean "host header" So when URL of my WEB APPS are different from http;//SharepointServerName it gives me this message

Comment: What is host header looks like? Is it entry in host file or A record from DNS?

Comment: None of those 2 as I do not assign any different IP to it.

Comment: What it looks like? I am little confused...is it fqdn?

Comment: Ha Thank you :) You solved my issue by pointing this very obvious question :) I did not add nothing to the host file. So now my web app http;//testing.server is working when i added 127.0.0.1 testing.server in host

Comment: Add your host name in your  dns and wgen u create webapplication add the host header name and re check  in iis bindings this host name exists

Comment: Great, I added that as answer, please mark it as answer if helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things to check

- your fqdn url(host header) if it is DNS a record then point to correct server
- if you are using host file entry, make sure it exists
- also check the AAM
- check IIS bindings as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and followed the advise from below link. it resolved my case.

1. Open IIS Manager on the server hosting Central Administration
2. Expand the server name and then select Application Pools
3. Select the SharePoint Central Administration v4 application pool.  In the Actions menu on the far right select Advanced Settings
4. Locate the Process Model Section and change the “Shutdown Time Limit” to a higher value.  I choose 300 for this environment
5. Close IIS and then initiate an IISRESET

[Solution](http://spmindmelt.focalpointsolutions.co/creating-new-web-application-error-this-page-cant-be-displayed-3/)